# How can I concat and insert two checkbox input arrays into db?

Tags: php

Ok I have a set of checkboxes with corresponding text inputs next to them. POST apparently sets a variable as an associative array, I want to be able to concat the values for the checkbox with the corresponding year by using a for loop and putting like indexes together. I'm currently getting an "unexpected [" error in the if statement. I looked into doing exactly this and found a few examples that went about this in the same way with success, what am I doing wrong?

Here is the form section

```
<form>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" Value = "Castle Connolly Top U.S. Doctor" id ="ccn"/>Castle Connolly Top U.S. Doctor</label>
            <input type="text" name="check_year" value="<?php echo decode_text($check_year);?>"/>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" Value = "Vitals Patients Choice"/>Vitals Patient's Choice</label>
            <input type="text" name="check_year" value="<?php echo decode_text($check_year);?>"/>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" Value = "Vitals Compassionate Doctor"/>Vital's Compassionate Doctor Recognition</label>
            <input type="text" name="check_year" value="<?php echo decode_text($check_year);?>"/>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" Value = "Super Doctor"/>Super Doctor</label>
            <input type="text" name="check_year" value="<?php echo decode_text($check_year);?>"/>
</form>
```

Then in my handler I have this code to get the values into separate arrays and concat them to another variable that I insert

```
$check_list = isset($_POST['check_list']) ? prepare_input($_POST['check_list']) : '';
$check_year = isset($_POST['check_year']) ? prepare_input($_POST['check_year']) : '';
$check_year_array = array_values($check_year);
$check_list_array = array_values($check_list);
$notable_awards .= ', ';

for($n=0; $n<5;$n++){
    if(!empty($check_list_array[$n])){
        $notable_awards .= $check_list_array[$n].','.$check_year_array[$n]; 
    }
}

$sql =  mysql_query("UPDATE" .TABLE_DOCTORS. " SET 
                    notable_awards = '".$notable_awards."' ,
                    notable_publications = '".$notable_publications."'
                    last_logged_ip = '".$user_ip."'
                    WHERE id =".$doctor_id);
```

Comment: Your `unexpected [` is not located in this code. However `$notable_awards .= ', ';` is a notice as you should not concat `null` with `', '`

Comment: There is an error and it tells me that message on line 38, which is the line the if statement is on. Also, the notable awards variable is not null, it's filled from another input box for additional awards, I want to have them all in one place

Comment: Are you looking in the correct include, cause again, I don't see the unexpected `[` in this code.